# Platform/Website that Supports Crowd-Funded WordPress Projects?

Tags: plugin-development

There are a couple of plugins that I'd like to have developed however I am poor so I'd love it if there was a platform that allowed me to easily group with others that have the same need and pool our resources to pay a developer.

I have seen a lot of freelance developer job boards and bidding platforms but I was wondering if there were any platforms out there that would specifically empower a group of users/designers to pool their money behind a project they like, and allow for developers to bid out the project?

The way I would envision it working would be a hybrid between [Freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com/) (or [elance.com](http://www.elance.com/)) and [Kickstarter.com](http://www.kickstarter.com/).  Actually, it would be similar to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) on the [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com/).

In case this doesn't exist, I'll elaborate on my idea for anyone that wants to make such a platform...

Basically, someone could post a project, take bids, then open it up for crowd funding or before any project is even bid on it could be open to a vote in the sense that people have to commit to at least $5 and once it reaches a certain commitment level it goes out for bids.

Comment: @Matt, It wouldn't hurt to post your plugin idea here.  There are a lot of plugin developers on this site and one of them might be willing to develop it or know of a similar plugin that could be modified to solve your problem.

Comment: *@matt*: +1 to the suggestion by *@Chris_O*. Also, maybe you should launch such a crowd-function site for WordPress Projects?

Comment: @Chris_O, Thanks for the suggestion, I will do that. 

@MikeSchinkel, I would love to develop such a site I just don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I posted one of the plugin help requests here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/help-creating-a-slideshow-custom-post-type-with-custom-meta-boxes

Comment: @matt I will be your first investor.  I have offered a 200 rep point bounty on your question and I challenge any user with more than 1k rep points to match or beat my investment.

Comment: I don't see how this is a relevant question. I suggest changing it to a wiki or closing it.

Comment: It's relevant because it is a question about a wordpress specific resource that would be useful to Wordpress administrators who are not developers.  I don't see how you'd think this is not relevant.  It may not useful to you, but it's a relevant Wordpress related question.

Comment: John wrote: *or* closing. The other idea was to convert it into a community wiki which I think is a good idea. If you edit your question, you can tick the Community Wiki checkbox. Then everybody can edit the question, e.g. to add links or to more differentially formulate the idea over time.

Comment: @hakre,  I tried but I'm not given the option to make it a community wiki.  I'll flag it for a moderator to wikify it.

Comment: it is a great idea - and if it is not there, we can collaborate and build it - count me in the team

Answer (score 1):

http://fundry.com/

Saw this one tweeted, has several WP-related projects/plugins in it already.

Comment: Good find!  That looks very cool.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have the ability for a funder to suggest a project, just to join on one that's already been submitted by a dev.